# Cloning an SXA site is not showing success message

Tags: sxa, item-clones

I tried cloning an Sxa Site but it keeps on showing "Running Script" message and didn't get Success message at all. Is there any way to find out the progress/status of cloning.

Comment: Have you checked logs for anything related to "sxa" or "cloning"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find this script in `master` database

```
/sitecore/system/Modules/PowerShell/Script Library/SXA/SXA - Site Manager/Functions/Run-SiteManager
```

Remove `Close-Window` from `end` section and save it.

Once the cloning is finished you will see **SiteManager** window.

[image]

> I tested it on **SXA 1.8**

### Jobs viewer

Open Jobs Viewer (`http://domain/sitecore/admin/jobs.aspx`)
[image]

and observer status of a job.

### Another way

If you are using the newest version of **SPE** you should distinguish whether cloning is in progress or not by looking at the progress bar. 
When cloning is running progress will change status, otherwise, it will be green without any animation.

Comment: Can we take the status in /sitecore/admin/jobs.aspx as granted?

Comment: @ManideepYechuri that's also a good way. I will add it to my answer.